# How can I rollback an app from F-droid without loosing settings?

Tags: applications, f-droid

My question follows the discussion under link [How to get an older version of an app from F-Droid?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248416/how-to-get-an-older-version-of-an-app-from-f-droid)
but the moderator unfortunately does not allow to ask for additional details in the same thread. So my question is the following:
I have installed a newer version of an app in F-droid to find out it becomes unusable because of bugs. Naturally I want to revert to the previous version. I pertinently know the older version can be seen in the versions section at the bottom. But I cannot install any of them unless I uninstall the current version of the app. This unfortunately results in loosing all settings.
How can I rollback an app from F-droid without loosing settings?

Comment: The answer is more or less the same as described here [Re-install app without losing personal data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55798/2241) As long as the formerly installed app and the older version are signed by the same key you can reinstall the older version after uninstalling the newer version via adb as described in the linked answer.

Comment: Note that the way described Love will only work if the old app version is capable of using the data from the new version. If the app author has changed the data format between both versions the may may not be able to load your data or even simply crash at start-up.

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question, although I was hoping F-droid or other package manager would have this very natural feature.

Comment: That is not possible because Android has to my knowledge no API for doing so. As an app you can only trigger an app installation.